# When parent of TextField is clickable hardware Enter/Return button triggers it's onClick

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Pretty simple layout. Parent with Modifier.clicakble(). Child TextField. When pressing "Enter/Return" key on hardware keyboard it adds new line in the TextField but ALSO triggers parent's onClick. Why? Is there a quick workaround?

```
                    Box(
                        Modifier.clickable {
                            Log.i("bullsh#t", "I've been clicked")
                        }
                    ) {
                        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

                        TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
                    }
```

For context, why would I need clickable parent. Modifier.clearFocusOnClick() that clears focus and hides keyabord when user taps anywhere outside the text field or other child clickable elements. Probably worth mentioning - child elements with Modifier.clickable work as expected and don't propagate click to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick workaround** is to add following *onKeyEvent* modifier to your TextField:

```
TextField(modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
    it.type == KeyEventType.KeyUp && it.key == Key.Enter
})
```

**Why?** This happens because of current *onKeyEvent* implementation used for TextField itself (method *androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.process()*) and then for *clickable* modifier:

1. KeyEventType.KeyDown event for pressed Enter is processed by TextField, new line is added, and event processing stopped (no propagation here)
2. On KeyEventType.KeyUp processing after some checks in above mentioned method, it does nothing but propagates event for further listeners:

   ```
   if (event.type != KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
       return false
   }
   ```
3. onKeyEvent used in *clickable* considers this as click (KeyUp on Enter key), so onClick is triggered